# Should I say "Are you student" or "Are you a student"?

Tags: articles

When asking someone whether he's student or not, should I use an article before the noun?

For example:

> Are you student or Are you **a** student?
>
> Are you policeman or Are you **a** policeman?
>
> Are you teacher or Are you **a** teacher?

I know that we use articles in declarative sentences, but I am not sure about interrogative sentences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Student”, “policeman”, and “teacher” are singular count nouns describing what someone is or what job they do. We use the indefinite article in such situations. E.g. “Are you a student?”, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer, if you are talking about a specific student, then use *the* (definite article) instead of *a* (indefinite article) Eg.

> Are you *the* student that got the highest marks in the examination?